# Would I lose principal if I bought a 2% 1-Year Bill for $103.0?

Tags: united-states, bonds, treasury

Would I lose principal if I bought a 2% 1-Year US Bill for $103.0 (`1000 + 20 - 1030 = -10`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes in that case you would have about a -1% yield.

While it may seem counterintuitive, it's actually quite common in some countries that are *discouraging* saving (by incentivizing people to spend or invest their money rather than save it) to prevent deflation.